# QDbusReply doesn't work calling a DBus function which returns a aa{sv} with Qt4?

Tags: qt4, qdbus

I have a dbus interface which works in d-feet as expected but when I want to call it from within my QT4 Application the list has zero size :(

I guess, aa{sv} can be used from Qt4 via QVariantList, right?

```
QDBusReply< QVariantList > reply = dbusinterface.call("getUsers");
QVariantList value = reply.value();
qDebug() << "user size: " << value.size();
```

Can't someone please shed some light on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I finally found a way to retrieve the correct list.
No garanties that it is "the way" but at least, it does what it should :).

```
QDBusMessage result = dbusinterface.call("getUsers");
QDBusArgument v = result.arguments()[0].value<QDBusArgument>();
QVariantMap m;
QVariantList l;

v.beginArray();
while(!v.atEnd()) {
    v >> m;
    l.append(m);
}

qDebug() << "users count: " << l.size();
```